# How to locate inner element after hovering (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, automation, ui-automation

I need to locate and click on My Account

[image]

I can see parent div header-menu-dropdown account-item then there is a child and that child have another child that contains two elements which is two href texts

I could potentially locate array of elements that have header-menu-item with-link class and then choose first element to locate what i need but is there a better way to do that?

[image]

Comment: //a[text()='My account']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wanna do, it would be something like this :

```
//div[@class='header-menu-item with-link']
```

and then you can either write :

```
//div[@class='header-menu-item with-link']/a
```

or if you have a web element with this `header-menu-item with-link`

directly use `.//a` with `findElement`

### Best practices

But personally, **I would not prefer to have xpath for this**

Please try

```
linkText
```

or

```
partialLinkText
```

since the element you are looking inside an **achor tag**, `linkText` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution is below (with linkText) :

```
@FindBy(linkText = "My account")
private WebElement myAccount;

public MyAccountPage openMyAccountPage() {
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(username).perform();
    actions.moveToElement(myAccount).click().perform();
    return new MyAccountPage(driver);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First **hover over** to the profile icon / your name, **then click** on the element.

```
By myAccountTxt = By.xpath("//a[text()='My account']");
By profileIcon = By.xpath("your profile icon xpath or custom xpath");
            
            // Moving cursor to the profile icon
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(profileIcon));
action.build().perform();

            // clicking the my account text
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(myAccountTxt));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(myAccountTxt));
driver.findElement(myAccountTxt).click();
```